# Not Binding properly

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection

So, I've got the following binding in WPF.

```xml
    <GroupBox Header="Nuværende Sang" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="165" Width="288">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="143" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276">
            <Grid.DataContext>
                <ETC:Song/>
            </Grid.DataContext>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="124" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Time}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Artist}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Album}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
```

The values always returns `null`, I know the strings and int are NOT `null`, for they are already used in this ListView:

```xml
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewSange" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="436" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="984" Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding Songs}" FontFamily="Malgun Gothic" FontSize="24" Margin="0,0,0,-12">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="No." DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ActiveIndex}" Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Song name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Width="700"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" Width="234"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

What I'm missing?

They are both referring to this class:

```xml
public class Song
{
    public string Title { get ; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    //public ImageBrush Portrait { get; set; }


    public Song(string title, string path, string artist, int time, string album)//, ImageBrush portrait)
    {
        this.Path = path;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Artist = artist;
        this.Time = time;
        this.Album = album;
        //this.Portrait = portrait;
    }

    public Song()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
```

Comment: Are you also using <Grid.DataContext> <ETC:Song/> </Grid.DataContext> in your listview's page?

Comment: No I'm not, hence the ItemsSource="{Binding Songs}" :)

Comment: Ok then what is <ETC:Song/> refering to? Could post the associated code?

Comment: I think that you're assigning an empty Song instance in your Grid DataContext (with <ETC:Song/>). Which would explain the empty values. What are you trying with this GroupBox/Grid?

Comment: Seems your right.. hmm, But I can't assign it to the other public :\

Comment: Where the song instance you want to bind comes from? ViewModel? Code behind?

Comment: I want to bound to the same as ListView.
That Itemsouce is directly bound to the observablecollection, from code behind.

Comment: But your listview is bound to several songs and your GroupBox/Grid can be bound to only one. It's not a list. Which song do you want to display?

Comment: The one currently playing, from MediaElement.

Comment: Are your Grid and your ListView located in the same page/window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using :

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <ETC:Song/>
 </Grid.DataContext>
```

Your are assigning an empty `Song` instance to your Grid `DataContext`. As the `DataContext` is inherited from parent, your `TextBlock` are probably bound to empty values coming from an empty Song instance.

Remove this piece of code, and set your `DataContext` with the `Song` instance you really want to display.

If your `ListView` and your `Grid` are located in the same page, i would advice you to create a dedicated property (in the same class and just next to the `List<Song>` property bound to your `ListView`, called `SongCurrentlyPlaying` for instance) and to bind your `TextBlock` that way :

```
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SongCurrentlyPlaying.Time}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SongCurrentlyPlaying.Artist}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SongCurrentlyPlaying.Album}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SongCurrentlyPlaying.Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="122"/>
```

Do not forget this new property has to make of use [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) or being a [DependancyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) so it can notify the view (and bindings) when its value has changed ;)